# run bash in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I want to creat a script to run an another script with a several parameter

```
exp=([1]=bloc [2]=ins [3]=rep [4]=op)
for j in ${!exp[*]}
do
    arr=([1]=mem [2]=gen [3]=usr)
    for i in ${!arr[*]}
    do
    var="bash createGnuploat.sh "${exp[j]}" ../Result/ 0" ${arr[i]} ${exp[j]}
    $var
    done
done
```

And i have this error :

```
run.sh: line 9: =bash createGnuploat.sh op ../Result/ 0: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

What's problem please ?

Comment: Read [BashFAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) if you haven't already.  Shell variables are *not* suitable containers for whole command-lines, in general.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In assignments, do not use `$` for variables you assign to: `var="..."`.

Comment: Also, don't give `bash` scripts `.sh` extensions - it's misleading.

Comment: @jw013 I always do that as well, what you suggest?

Comment: @warl0ck I normally just leave off the extension since it's the shebang line that matters anyways.  However if I want an explicit reminder that "this is a `bash` script", in the name of the file, `.bash` works.  Either way is better than `.sh` which implies `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store a command in a variable, don't use a string, that just can't work. See [Bash FAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Use a function or an array.

Your line is parsed as the assignment `var="bash createGnuploat.sh "${exp[j]}" ../Result/ 0"` followed by the two words `${arr[i]}` (which will be taken as a command name) and `${exp[j]}` (which will be the first and only argument to the command). Check the syntax highlighting in your question or in your editor, it shows what is inside the quoted string.

Always use double quotes around variable substitutions, e.g. `"$foo"`. Otherwise the value of the variable is split into words that are interpreted as glob patterns. (Omit the double quotes in the 0.01% of the cases where this is desired behavior.) For an array, use `"${foo[@]}"` to have each element of the array in a separate word (`"${foo[*]}"` is a single word with the elements of the array separated by spaces; if you leave out the quotes, then each element is broken into separate words that are interpreted as glob patterns).

Here's your snippet rewritten using a function:

```
create_plot () {
  bash createGnuploat.sh "${exp[$2]}" ../Result/ 0 "${arr[$1]}" "${exp[$2]}"
}

for j in "${!exp[@]}"
do
    arr=([1]=mem [2]=gen [3]=usr)
    for i in "${!arr[@]}"
    do
      create_plot "$i" "$j"
    done
done
```

For the rare cases where it makes sense to use an array variable instead of a function:

```
for j in "${!exp[@]}"
do
    arr=([1]=mem [2]=gen [3]=usr)
    for i in "${!arr[@]}"
    do
      var=(bash createGnuploat.sh "${exp[j]}" ../Result/ 0 "${arr[i]}" "${exp[j]}")
      "${var[@]}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple syntax and quoting issues in the line

```
$var="bash createGnuploat.sh "${exp[j]}" ../Result/ 0" ${arr[i]} ${exp[j]}
```

Here is a cleaner version of the script in your question:

```
for j in bloc ins rep op; do
        for i in mem gen usr; do
                bash createGnuploat.sh "$j" ../Result/ 0 "$i" "$j"
        done
done
```

I don't know what the arguments are supposed to be for `createGnuploat.sh` so you'll have to check that yourself.

Comment: The problem is not in createGnuploat.sh an not arguments, i can run it directly with same arguments. But in my case i want to know how to run a commande (bash createGnuploat.sh "$j" ../Result/ 0 "$i" "$j" ) writed in bash file ?

Comment: @user15992 Edit your question and insert a description of what you are trying to accomplish.